# DB Unit TypeCastException

Tags: sql-server, spring, annotations, dbunit, hibernate-onetomany

I'm trying to setup unit tests for my simple application, but when setting up my test data, I always get a TypeCast error.

Here the needed info:

1) Database schema:

```
USE [EDIKANBAN]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

IF EXISTS
(
    SELECT  *
    FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    WHERE   TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'
    AND TABLE_NAME = 'CONTACTASSIGNEDROLES'
)
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CONTACTASSIGNEDROLES] DROP CONSTRAINT FK_CONTACTDETAILS_CONTACTASSIGNEDROLES
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CONTACTASSIGNEDROLES] DROP CONSTRAINT FK_CONTACTASSIGNEDROLES_CONTACTROLE
    --ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CONTACTASSIGNEDROLES] DROP CONSTRAINT FK_CONTACTASSIGNEDROLES_CONTACTRESPONSIBILITY
    DROP TABLE [dbo].[CONTACTASSIGNEDROLES]
END
GO

IF EXISTS
(
    SELECT  *
    FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    WHERE   TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'
    AND TABLE_NAME = 'CONTACTDETAILS'
)
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE [dbo].[CONTACTDETAILS]
END
GO

IF EXISTS
(
    SELECT  *
    FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    WHERE   TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'
    AND TABLE_NAME = 'CONTACTROLE'
)
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE [dbo].[CONTACTROLE]
END
GO

IF EXISTS
(
    SELECT  *
    FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    WHERE   TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'
    AND TABLE_NAME = 'CONTACTRESPONSIBILITY'
)
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE [dbo].[CONTACTRESPONSIBILITY]
END
GO

IF EXISTS
(
    SELECT  *
    FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    WHERE   TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'
    AND TABLE_NAME = 'CONTACTROLE'
)
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE [dbo].[CONTACTROLE]
END
GO

/************************************************************************************/
/****** Object: Table [dbo].[CONTACTROLE]  Script Date: 06/02/2014 10:04:11 ******/
/************************************************************************************/
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CONTACTROLE](
    [ID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [ROLE] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_CONTACTROLE] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

/**********************************************************************************************/
/****** Object: Table [dbo].[CONTACTRESPONSIBILITY]  Script Date: 06/02/2014 10:03:57 ******/
/**********************************************************************************************/
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CONTACTRESPONSIBILITY](
    [ID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [RESPONSIBILITY] [varchar](80) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_CONTACTRESPONSIBILITY] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

/***************************************************************************************/
/****** Object: Table [dbo].[CONTACTDETAILS]  Script Date: 04/02/2014 11:05:27 ******/
/***************************************************************************************/
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CONTACTDETAILS](
    [ID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [SUPPLIER_CODE] [varchar](5) NOT NULL,
    [NAME] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [TELEPHONE] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [MOBILE] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [FAX] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [EMAIL] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [CREATED_DATE] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [CREATED_USER] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [MODIFIED_DATE] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [MODIFIED_USER] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_CONTACTDETAILS] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

/*********************************************************************************************/
/****** Object: Table [dbo].[CONTACTASSIGNEDROLES]  Script Date: 06/02/2014 10:03:34 ******/
/*********************************************************************************************/
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CONTACTASSIGNEDROLES](
    [ID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [DETAILS_ID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [ROLE_ID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [RESPONSIBILITY_ID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [DOCK_CODE] [char](5) NULL,
    [COMMENT] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [CREATED_DATE] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [CREATED_USER] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [MODIFIED_DATE] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [MODIFIED_USER] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_CONTACTASSIGNEDROLES] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CONTACTASSIGNEDROLES] WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_CONTACTDETAILS_CONTACTASSIGNEDROLES] FOREIGN KEY([DETAILS_ID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[CONTACTDETAILS] ([ID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CONTACTASSIGNEDROLES] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_CONTACTDETAILS_CONTACTASSIGNEDROLES]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CONTACTASSIGNEDROLES] WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_CONTACTASSIGNEDROLES_CONTACTROLE] FOREIGN KEY([ROLE_ID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[CONTACTROLE] ([ID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CONTACTASSIGNEDROLES] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_CONTACTASSIGNEDROLES_CONTACTROLE]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CONTACTASSIGNEDROLES]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_CONTACTASSIGNEDROLES_CONTACTRESPONSIBILITY] FOREIGN KEY([RESPONSIBILITY_ID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[CONTACTRESPONSIBILITY] ([ID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CONTACTASSIGNEDROLES] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_CONTACTASSIGNEDROLES_CONTACTRESPONSIBILITY]
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
```

2) Java objects corresponding to the tables:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CONTACTROLE")
public class ContactRole {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "ROLE", length = 80)
    @Size(min = 0, max = 80)
    private String role;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "contactRole")
    private Set<ContactAssignedRole> contactAssignedRoles;  

}


@Entity
@Table(name = "CONTACTRESPONSIBILITY")
public class ContactResponsibility {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "RESPONSIBILITY", length = 80)
    @Size(min = 0, max = 80)
    private String responsibility;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "contactResponsibility")
    private Set<ContactAssignedRole> contactAssignedRoles;


@Entity
@Table(name = "CONTACTDETAILS")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class ContactDetails extends ServiceModel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "SUPPLIER_CODE", length = 5)
    @Size(min = 5, max = 5)
    private String supplierCode;

    @Column(name = "NAME", length = 100)
    @Size(min = 0, max = 100)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "TELEPHONE", nullable = true, length = 80)
    @Size(max = 80)
    private String telephone;

    @Column(name = "MOBILE", nullable = true, length = 80)
    @Size(max = 80)
    private String mobile;

    @Column(name = "FAX", nullable = true, length = 80)
    @Size(max = 80)
    private String fax;

    @Column(name = "EMAIL", nullable = true, length = 100)
    @Size(max = 100)
    private String email;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "contactDetails")
    private Set<ContactAssignedRole> contactAssignedRoles;


@Entity
@Table(name = "CONTACTASSIGNEDROLES")
public class ContactAssignedRole extends ServiceModel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "DETAILS_ID")
    @NotNull
    private ContactDetails contactDetails;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ROLE_ID")
    private ContactRole contactRole;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "RESPONSIBILITY_ID")
    private ContactResponsibility contactResponsibility;

    @Column(name = "DOCK_CODE", length = 5)
    @Size(min = 0, max = 5)
    private String dockCode;

    @Column(name = "COMMENT", length = 100)
    @Size(min = 0, max = 100)
    private String comment;
```

3) Dataset xml file

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<dataset>
<CONTACTRESPONSIBILITY
        ID="1"
        RESPONSIBILITY="DEFAULT"
    />
    <CONTACTRESPONSIBILITY
        ID="2"
        RESPONSIBILITY="TMMF"
    />
    <CONTACTRESPONSIBILITY
        ID="3"
        RESPONSIBILITY="TMUKB"
    />
    <CONTACTRESPONSIBILITY
        ID="4"
        RESPONSIBILITY="TMUKD"
    />
    <CONTACTRESPONSIBILITY
        ID="5"
        RESPONSIBILITY="TMMP"
    />
    <CONTACTRESPONSIBILITY
        ID="6"
        RESPONSIBILITY="TMIP"
    />
    <CONTACTRESPONSIBILITY
        ID="7"
        RESPONSIBILITY="TMMT"
    />
    <CONTACTRESPONSIBILITY
        ID="8"
        RESPONSIBILITY="SERVICE"
    />
    <CONTACTRESPONSIBILITY
        ID="9"
        RESPONSIBILITY="EXPORT"
    />
    <CONTACTROLE
        ID="1"
        ROLE="DAILY CONTACT"
    />
    <CONTACTROLE
        ID="2"
        ROLE="BACK-UP CONTACT"
    />
    <CONTACTROLE
        ID="3"
        ROLE="PRENOTIFICATION CONTACT"
    />
    <CONTACTROLE
        ID="4"
        ROLE="LOGISTICS CONTACT"
    />
    <CONTACTROLE
        ID="5"
        ROLE="AF CONTACT"
    />
    <CONTACTROLE
        ID="6"
        ROLE="EMERGENCY CONTACT 1"
    />
    <CONTACTROLE
        ID="7"
        ROLE="EMERGENCY CONTACT 2"
    />
    <CONTACTROLE
        ID="8"
        ROLE="PLANT MANAGER"
    />
    <CONTACTROLE
        ID="9"
        ROLE="MANAGING DIRECTOR"
    />
    <CONTACTROLE
        ID="10"
        ROLE="SCM ORDERS EMAIL RECEIVER"
    />
    <CONTACTDETAILS 
        ID="1" 
        SUPPLIER_CODE="SUP11" 
        NAME="NAME-11111" 
        TELEPHONE="+32 2 111.11.11" 
        MOBILE="+32 499 111.111" 
        EMAIL="TEST11111@TOYOTA-EUROPE" 
        CREATED_DATE="2014-02-05 01:01:01" 
        CREATED_USER="testUser1@TARS"
        MODIFIED_DATE="2014-02-05 01:01:01" 
        MODIFIED_USER="testUser1@TARS"
    />
    <CONTACTDETAILS 
        ID="2" 
        SUPPLIER_CODE="SUP22" 
        NAME="NAME-22222" 
        TELEPHONE="+32 2 222.22.22" 
        MOBILE="+32 499 222.222" 
        EMAIL="TEST22222@TOYOTA-EUROPE" 
        CREATED_DATE="2014-02-05 02:02:02" 
        CREATED_USER="testUser2@TARS"
        MODIFIED_DATE="2014-02-05 02:02:02" 
        MODIFIED_USER="testUser2@TARS"
    />
    <CONTACTDETAILS
        ID="3" 
        SUPPLIER_CODE="SUP33" 
        NAME="NAME-33333" 
        TELEPHONE="+32 2 333.33.33" 
        MOBILE="+32 499 333.333" 
        EMAIL="TEST33333@TOYOTA-EUROPE"
        CREATED_DATE="2014-02-05 03:03:03" 
        CREATED_USER="testUser3@TARS"
        MODIFIED_DATE="2014-02-05 03:03:03" 
        MODIFIED_USER="testUser3@TARS"
     />
    <CONTACTDETAILS 
        ID="4" 
        SUPPLIER_CODE="SUP44" 
        NAME="NAME-44444" 
        TELEPHONE="+32 2 444.44.44" 
        MOBILE="+32 499 444.444" 
        EMAIL="TEST44444@TOYOTA-EUROPE"
        CREATED_DATE="2014-02-05 04:04:04" 
        CREATED_USER="testUser4@TARS"
        MODIFIED_DATE="2014-02-05 04:04:04" 
        MODIFIED_USER="testUser4@TARS" 
    />
    <CONTACTASSIGNEDROLES
        ID="1"
        DETAILS_ID="1"
        ROLE_ID="1"
        RESPONSIBILITY_ID="1"
        DOCK_CODE="11"
        COMMENT="This is comment number one."
        CREATED_DATE="2014-02-01 01:01:01"
        CREATED_USER="testUser1@TARS"
        MODIFIED_DATE="2014-02-05 01:01:01"
        MODIFIED_USER="testUser1@TARS"
    />
    <CONTACTASSIGNEDROLES
        ID="2"
        DETAILS_ID="2"
        ROLE_ID="2"
        RESPONSIBILITY_ID="2"
        DOCK_CODE="22"
        COMMENT="This is comment number two."
        CREATED_DATE="2014-02-02 02:02:02"
        CREATED_USER="testUser2@TARS"
        MODIFIED_DATE="2014-02-02 02:02:02"
        MODIFIED_USER="testUser2@TARS"
    />  
    <CONTACTASSIGNEDROLES
        ID="3"
        DETAILS_ID="3"
        ROLE_ID="3"
        RESPONSIBILITY_ID="3"
        DOCK_CODE="33"
        COMMENT="This is comment number three."
        CREATED_DATE="2014-02-03 03:03:03"
        CREATED_USER="testUser3@TARS"
        MODIFIED_DATE="2014-02-03 03:03:03"
        MODIFIED_USER="testUser3@TARS"
    />  
    <CONTACTASSIGNEDROLES
        ID="4"
        DETAILS_ID="4"
        ROLE_ID="4"
        RESPONSIBILITY_ID="4"
        DOCK_CODE="44"
        COMMENT="This is comment number four."
        CREATED_DATE="2014-02-04 04:04:04"
        CREATED_USER="testUser4@TARS"
        MODIFIED_DATE="2014-02-04 04:04:04"
        MODIFIED_USER="testUser4@TARS"
    />
    <CONTACTASSIGNEDROLES
        ID="5"
        DETAILS_ID=""
        ROLE_ID="5"
        RESPONSIBILITY_ID="5"
        DOCK_CODE="55"
        COMMENT="This is comment number five."
        CREATED_DATE="2014-02-05 05:05:05"
        CREATED_USER="testUser5@TARS"
        MODIFIED_DATE="2014-02-05 05:05:05"
        MODIFIED_USER="testUser5@TARS"
    />
</dataset>
```

4) The test that I'm trying to execute:

```
public class ContactAssignedRoleServiceTest extends AbstractServiceTest {
    @SpringBeanByName
    private ContactAssignedRoleService contactAssignedRoleService;

    @Test
    @DataSet(value = "ContactAssignedRoleServiceTest.xml")
    public void testFindContactAssignedRoles() {

        List<ContactAssignedRole> dbContactAssignedRoles = contactAssignedRoleService.find();

        Assert.assertNotNull("Contact Details is null", dbContactAssignedRoles);
        Assert.assertEquals("Wrong number of records returned", 5, dbContactAssignedRoles.size());
        ContactAssignedRole dbContactAssignedRole = dbContactAssignedRoles.get(0);
        Assert.assertNotNull("Contact Assigned Role is null", dbContactAssignedRole);
        Assert.assertEquals("Wrong ID", 1, dbContactAssignedRole.getId().longValue());
        Assert.assertEquals("Wrong Contact Id", "1", dbContactAssignedRole.getContactDetails().getId());
        Assert.assertEquals("Wrong Role", "DAILY CONTACT", dbContactAssignedRole.getContactRole().getRole());
        Assert.assertEquals("Wrong Responsibility", "DEFAULT", dbContactAssignedRole.getContactResponsibility().getResponsibility());
        Assert.assertEquals("Wrong Dock", "11", dbContactAssignedRole.getDockCode());
        Assert.assertEquals("Wrong Comment", null, dbContactAssignedRole.getComment());
    }
}
```

5) The error that I'm getting:

```
org.unitils.core.UnitilsException: Error inserting test data from DbUnit dataset for method public void com.toyota.tme.edikanban.service.ContactAssignedRoleServiceTest.testFindContactAssignedRoles()
    at org.unitils.dbunit.DbUnitModule.insertDataSet(DbUnitModule.java:156)
    at org.unitils.dbunit.DbUnitModule$DbUnitListener.beforeTestSetUp(DbUnitModule.java:557)
    at org.unitils.core.Unitils$UnitilsTestListener.beforeTestSetUp(Unitils.java:273)
    at org.unitils.UnitilsJUnit4TestClassRunner$TestListenerInvokingMethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(UnitilsJUnit4TestClassRunner.java:151)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:84)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:49)
    at org.unitils.UnitilsJUnit4TestClassRunner.invokeTestMethod(UnitilsJUnit4TestClassRunner.java:95)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.runMethods(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:61)
    at org.unitils.UnitilsJUnit4TestClassRunner.access$000(UnitilsJUnit4TestClassRunner.java:44)
    at org.unitils.UnitilsJUnit4TestClassRunner$1.run(UnitilsJUnit4TestClassRunner.java:62)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:34)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:44)
    at org.unitils.UnitilsJUnit4TestClassRunner.run(UnitilsJUnit4TestClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: org.unitils.core.UnitilsException: Error while executing DataSetLoadStrategy
    at org.unitils.dbunit.datasetloadstrategy.impl.BaseDataSetLoadStrategy.execute(BaseDataSetLoadStrategy.java:46)
    at org.unitils.dbunit.DbUnitModule.insertDataSet(DbUnitModule.java:230)
    at org.unitils.dbunit.DbUnitModule.insertDataSet(DbUnitModule.java:153)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: org.dbunit.dataset.datatype.TypeCastException: Error casting value for table 'CONTACTASSIGNEDROLES' and column 'DETAILS_ID'
    at org.dbunit.operation.AbstractBatchOperation.execute(AbstractBatchOperation.java:208)
    at org.dbunit.operation.CompositeOperation.execute(CompositeOperation.java:78)
    at org.unitils.dbunit.datasetloadstrategy.impl.CleanInsertLoadStrategy.doExecute(CleanInsertLoadStrategy.java:45)
    at org.unitils.dbunit.datasetloadstrategy.impl.BaseDataSetLoadStrategy.execute(BaseDataSetLoadStrategy.java:44)
    ... 20 more
```

Any idea about what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: It looks like DETAILS_ID is a not nullable column, as well as a FK to the ID column, and your one dataset has "".  Also, is there a reason you are using bigint?  Does Java have the capability to translate that to Long implicitly?

Comment: Ok, the issue is closed.
I had indeed one of the DETAILS_ID that wasn't set in in the last CONTACTDETAILS tag...always checked the first one, so the last one was overlooked.
Regarding the conversion from bigint to Long, this seems to be handled very well.